Continuous $4\pi$ steradian monitoring of space
What would it take to constantly survey space at a selection of frequencies? I'm imagining a set of satellites pointing away from the Earth and scanning all sectors of space. Can anyone point me to some ideas in this direction?

At visible wavelengths it is far cheaper to do this with a network of ground-based telescopes (distributed around the globe). Something like that was developed using the CONCAM telescopes (e.g., Shamir 2006) but there appears to be very little literature on subsequent developments.
Most activity on all-sky detection of transients focuses on gamma rays and X-rays, which must be sited in space to avoid the Earth's atmosphere. There are many such missions that have this capability - either to scan the whole sky with a short duty cycle (e.g., MAXI-ISS), single satellites that can monitor all the sky not occluded by the Earth (e.g., the Fermi Gamma Ray Burst Monitor) or multiple satellites to monitor all or most of the X-ray/Gamma ray sky (e.g., GECAM).
